# Vertex Switch DX

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, vertex, directx-9

So my problem is kinda simple. I have a vertex buffer, I create it with

```
    pDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(
        m_dwCount * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX)),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &m_pVB, NULL);
```

and then let's say for test purposes, I want to modify all of them and multiply them. How exactly can I lock all of them and then multiply them? I tried to lock it

```
    CUSTOMVERTEX* pVoid;
    pVB->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
```

but that I assume doesn't lock the entire buffer. I'm kinda new to the DirectX so I'm sorry if the question is too stupid, however thanks anyone for help.

Comment: Instead of using legacy Direct3D 9 which requires using the deprecated DirectX SDK and the deprecated D3DX9 library, use DirectX 11 instead. In that case, the ``PrimitiveBatch`` class in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) implements the dynamic submission model nicely. The only reason to learn Direct3D 9 today is to support Windows XP which is largely gone in most markets and is quickly disappearing even in China/Korea/Russia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create your multiplied vertices (for example called `newVertices`). Then you need to `lock` your vertex buffer and get the pointer to pointer of current vertices like this :

```
CUSTOMVERTEX* pVertices;
HRESULT hr = m_pVB->Lock(0, 0, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVertices), 0);
```

Then you can use `memcpy` to replace your new vertices into it like this :

```
if(hr == S_OK)
    memcpy(pVertices, newVertices, num_of_vertices * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
```

Then `unlock` you vertex buffer like this :

```
hr = m_pVB->Unlock();
```